# i have a big delay when i did use AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

i have a delay for 30 sec when i used ajax to replace part of page when i did removed ajax function and reloaded the hole page the precess going faster ..

blade file

```
<button  type="button"   class="btn category" id="moveto" name="singer" value="top_votes"  ><h6>Top 
 Rated</h6></button>    
<button  type="button"  class="btn category" id="moveto" name="singer" value="linkin_park" ><h6>Linkin 
park</h6></button>
```

controller file

```
public function selectamr()
    {
        
        $songs=Song::orderBy('votes', 'DESC')->paginate(3);
        return view('songs.selected',compact('songs'));
        
    }
    public function selectlinkin()
    {
        
        $songs=DB::table('songs')->where("singer", "linkin park")->paginate(12);
        return view('songs.selected',compact('songs'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 12);
    }
```

js file

```
$(".btn.category").click(function(){
     var thevaleu= $(this).val();
  
    $.ajax({url: "/"+thevaleu, success: function(result){
      $("#container").html(result);
    }});
  });

web.file

Route::get('/top_votes','SelectController@selectamr');
Route::get('/linkin_park','SelectController@selectlinkin');
```

Comment: It's not clear what is your question, can you explain a little more?

Comment: I wonder if caching may be a part of the delay.  If you start the server and run a version w/o Ajax does it take a similar amount of time as w/ Ajax?

Comment: @Camilo not really a question its working fine but it takes too long to impelement dont know why

Comment: @object Object yes if i removed ajax function it works fast with no delay

Comment: What's the exact amount of time in the network tab the request takes?  As well as that how long does it take for the server to receive the request and then return the result?

Comment: @objectObject if you meant without using ajax it takes 7 second

Comment: How many songs are in your table, and are the tables indexes setup correctly? This sounds like an issue with music or incorrect indexes where the queries take a long time.